# Using Ripley's K-Function and Kernel Density Estimation?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, kernel-density

Having issues applying Ripley's K-Function and Kernel Density to apply to ACLED (Armed Conflict Location & Event Data) point pattern analysis.

The issues relates to how do you know the correct distance increment for Ripley's and output cell size and search radius for kernel density based on the data you are faced with.